# Mock() function gives TypeError in django2

Tags: python, django, mocking, tdd, django-2.0

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_purist_unit_tests.html).

When I run `test_views.py` I have an error that shouldn't be there according the author: `TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes`.

My `views` and my `test_views` are the same like the book, but I'm using django 2.0.6 instead django 1.11 so my `url.py` change, so maybe here's the problem.

**Edit:**

at a second look the problem appears to be in the `mock()` function.

When I use `patch('lists.views.List')` the `Print(list_)` in my view gives `<MagicMock name='List()' id='79765800'>` instead of `List object (1)`

**/edit**

My `lists/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new', views.new_list, name='new_list'),
    path('<slug:list_id>/',
        views.view_list, name='view_list'),
    path('users/<email>/',         # I'm not sure about this one but it works in other tests
        views.my_lists, name='my_lists'),
]
#instead of:
#urlpatterns = [
#    url(r'^new$', views.new_list, name='new_list'),
#    url(r'^(\d+)/$', views.view_list, name='view_list'),
#    url(r'^users/(.+)/$', views.my_lists, name='my_lists'),
#]
```

My `lists/views.py`:

```
[...]
def new_list(request):
    form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        list_ = List()
        list_.owner = request.user
        list_.save()
        form.save(for_list=list_)
        Print(list_)
        return redirect(list_)
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form})
```

My `lists/tests/test_views.py`:

```
@patch('lists.views.List')
@patch('lists.views.ItemForm')
def test_list_owner_is_saved_if_user_is_authenticated(self, 
    mockItemFormClass, mockListClass
):
    user = User.objects.create(email='a@b.com')
    self.client.force_login(user)
    self.client.post('/lists/new', data={'text': 'new item'})
    mock_list = mockListClass.return_value
    self.assertEqual(mock_list.owner, user)
```

My full traceback:

> TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

[image: traceback]

What can be?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last I found the solution on-line.

[Django 2 doesn't support anymore bytestrings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#removed-support-for-bytestrings-in-some-places) in some places so when the views redirect the mock Class List it does as a mock object and the `iri_to_uri` django function throws an error. In django 1.11 `iri_to_uri` forced the iri to a bytes `return quote(force_bytes(iri), safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")` instead now is `return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")`. So the solution is to `return redirect(str(list_.get_absolute_url()))` instead of `return redirect(list_)` in the `lists.views.py`

```
def new_list(request):
    form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        list_ = List()
        list_.owner = request.user
        list_.save()
        form.save(for_list=list_)
        #return redirect(list_)
        return redirect(str(list_.get_absolute_url()))
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form})
```

I hope this helps someone else

Comment: Oh, yes, absolutely helpful! Thank you so much! I'm using Django 3. But I don't understand why the problem only shows up with using the mock library. Without it, `redirect(list_)` works just fine. There must be more to this.

Comment: This solution is simple enough to unblock people using latest Django for the tutorial. love it!

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this in the testing code without changing the desired production code as follows:

```
@patch('lists.views.NewListForm')
class NewListViewUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.request = HttpRequest()
        self.request.POST['text'] = 'new list item'
        self.request.user = Mock()

def test_passes_POST_data_to_NewListForm(self, mockNewListForm):
    mock_form = mockNewListForm.return_value
    returned_object = mock_form.save.return_value
    returned_object.get_absolute_url.return_value = 'fakeurl'

    new_list2(self.request)

    mockNewListForm.assert_called_once_with(data=self.request.POST)

def test_saves_form_with_owner_if_form_valid(self, mockNewListForm):
    mock_form = mockNewListForm.return_value
    mock_form.is_valid.return_value = True
    returned_object = mock_form.save.return_value
    returned_object.get_absolute_url.return_value = 'fakeurl'

    new_list2(self.request)

    mock_form.save.assert_called_once_with(owner=self.request.user)

@patch('lists.views.redirect')
def test_redirects_to_form_returned_object_if_form_valid(
    self, mock_redirect, mockNewListForm
):
    mock_form = mockNewListForm.return_value
    mock_form.is_valid.return_value = True

    response = new_list2(self.request)

    self.assertEqual(response, mock_redirect.return_value)
    mock_redirect.assert_called_once_with(mock_form.save.return_value)
```

Note that assigning `some_method.return_value` sets the response of `some_method`, **without calling** `some_method()`, so we can also test that the method was only called once.

What I like about this solution is that it results in the desired production code:

```
def new_list2(request):
    form = NewListForm(data=request.POST)
    list_ = form.save(owner=request.user)
    return redirect(list_)
```

.. instead of using a workaround in the production code like `return redirect(str(list_.get_absolute_url()))`, which is not desirable because it:

1. Is not the desired production code
2. Is less elegant production code
3. Just returns the name of the mocked object as a string (i.e. `<MagicMock name='NewListForm().save().get_absolute_url()' id='4363470544'>`), which is not what we want: we want to call the `get_absolute_url()` method and **that** method (not `str()`) should return a url as a string.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It is far more elegant and does not interfere with the code base at all.  Works wiith django 4.04

Comment: It is more elegant, but it doesn't refer to the code from the question, which leaves those of us unclear on mocks still at sea.